# Console Window Color, KeyUp, KeyDown and KeyPress Events

Tags: c#, colors, console-application, keypress

1) How do I change the background color so it will looks like this?

[image: screenshot]

ConsoleColor only changes lines with text, I need to change the whole screen; so don't say ConsoleColor.

2) How do I use KeyUp, KeyDown and KeyPress Event? And how can I set different actions for different keys?
I found a lot of guides on these events, though I am just starting to use C#, so an explanation (and not just the code) will be preferred.

Comment: Are you sure you want events or you just want to detect if user inserted some character? Do you want to change color of the console based on these events?

Answer (score 4):

> How do I change the background color

You have to clear the console *after* setting the [BackgroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor.aspx) e.g.

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Clear();
```

> How do I use KeyUp, KeyDown and KeyPress Event?

You would use [Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx) and handle each key type e.g.

```
var input = Console.ReadKey();
switch (input.Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
        // handle left arrow
        break:
    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
        // handle right arrow
        break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, It works and I know how to use it, But I dont know how it works, So I wont be able to implument it into other uses...

Comment: @user1823701 Don't know how what works? Implement it for what other uses? Can you be a little more specific... Also the latter is out the scope of your original question.